# Celery. Create too many tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I run the same code on my local computer and remote. I don't understand why, in the local case, one worker and one task are launched. In the case of the remote computer, celery creates five tasks.

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "create_new_avatar": {
        "task": "telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar",
        "schedule": crontab(),
    }
}
```

I would like celery to do one task in one minute.

I am run : `celery worker -A config.celery_app -B -l info -n other --concurrency=1`

Result on local computer:

```
[tasks]
  . telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar

[2021-02-28 17:50:04,651: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2021-02-28 17:50:04,672: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-02-28 17:50:05,591: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2021-02-28 17:50:05,676: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task create_new_avatar (telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar)
[2021-02-28 17:50:06,064: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-02-28 17:50:06,102: INFO/MainProcess] celery@other ready.
[2021-02-28 17:50:06,119: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar[827646b1-6587-4de9-b7b8-1fdc3f6a8d08]  
[2021-02-28 17:50:07,022: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
[2021-02-28 17:50:07,299: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Connection to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
[2021-02-28 17:50:08,323: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Uploading file of 108247 bytes in 1 chunks of 131072
[2021-02-28 17:50:09,379: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Uploading file of 108247 bytes in 1 chunks of 131072
[2021-02-28 17:50:10,602: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Disconnecting from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
[2021-02-28 17:50:10,603: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Disconnection from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
[2021-02-28 17:50:10,616: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Avatar is changed in 2021-02-28 17:50:10.615904
```

But the same thing looks different on the remote server.

```
[tasks]
  . telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar

[2021-02-28 18:01:37,130: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2021-02-28 18:01:37,153: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2021-02-28 18:01:37,182: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-02-28 18:01:37,250: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task create_new_avatar (telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar)
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,238: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,256: INFO/MainProcess] celery@other ready.
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,271: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar[e3690979-cd2a-4413-b5ad-f99a8e7cc44a]  
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,272: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar[b872d117-b4c7-4538-8c38-d07ad1e16164]  
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,273: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar[b0e1470e-7bb7-41c2-bf38-613399266e8c]  
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,273: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar[290f86ce-5be9-4606-aa42-fe8c0ef55ebf]  
[2021-02-28 18:01:38,381: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: telegram_user.tasks.telegram_change_avatar[10138e04-6bf9-4ee3-a134-f771b4002b3e]  
[2021-02-28 18:01:39,647: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
[2021-02-28 18:01:39,657: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Connection to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
[2021-02-28 18:01:39,858: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Uploading file of 102594 bytes in 1 chunks of 131072
[2021-02-28 18:01:39,938: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Uploading file of 102594 bytes in 1 chunks of 131072
[2021-02-28 18:01:40,132: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Disconnecting from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
[2021-02-28 18:01:40,133: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Disconnection from 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete!
[2021-02-28 18:01:40,143: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Avatar is changed in 2021-02-28 18:01:40.143742
```

Why are five tasks being created? How can this be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
celery -A proj purge
```

Got it. If someone can explain why this could happen, I would be very grateful.Unfortunately, I didn't understand the real reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting up all of your workers with `-B`, that is likely your problem.  celery-beat must be run as a singleton (e.g., you can only ever have one instance of celery beat running for a given broker).